# DynamoDB Local deletes data after shutting down instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm using DynamoDB Local for my app, and it keeps deleting all the sample data every time I shut down the instance. Does anyone know why this happens? 
I've tried to look it up, but I don't see anyone else has this issue.
I've used the downloadable version of dynamodb and use this command `dynamodb_local_latest baopham$ java -Djava.library.path=./DynoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -inMemory` to start and instance.
Am I missing anything? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DynamoDB local usage documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html) clearly states that if use `-inMemory` option, data will be in memory and data will be lost when you terminate. Take out `-inMemory` option in your command.

> If you use the -inMemory option, DynamoDB does not write any database files at all. Instead, all data is written to memory, and the data is not saved when you terminate DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

for docker, this command worked for me

```
docker run --name dynamodb -p 8000:8000 -d amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```